# How to split rows in Spotfire data table?

Tags: spotfire

I have 3 applications App1, App2 and App3. I need a report the number of issues that has come per report. The App category column has all these 3 values. However there are issue that impact all the applications (common to all apps). So they are marked as all. My report should have count against 3 Applications only. So whenever I have an 'All' type I need to show it against all the 3 applications.

```
App1 - 3
App2 - 2
App3 - 1
All  - 2
```

It should show:-

```
App1 - 5
App2 - 4
App3 - 3
```

Is it possible to do it at the data table level in spotfire?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you trying to display this? CrossTable or BarChart or....?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a calculated column that does this for you. Then instead of displaying the "Number of Issues" column, you would display the new calculated column instead. The expression for the calculated column would be:

```
Integer([Issues] + Sum(If([App Name]="All",[Issues],0)))
```

For a table table as shown here:
[Data Table Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdCt0.png)

Now, if you don't want the 'All' row to be displayed or included in your visualizations at all, you can always use filtering, or limit the data at the visualization level, through an expression. The latter can be done by right-clicking on a visualization and going to Properties > Data > Limit Data Using Expression (Edit) and inserting the following expression

```
[App Name]!='All'
```

I hope this helps.